# General solution for relative ~path to absolute url?

Tags: c#, uri

I have a **Uri instance** from some request.
And I've got **"~/Pages/SomePage.aspx"**.

```
var uri = new Uri("http://www.contoso.com/");
var relativeUrl = "~/Pages/SomePage.aspx";
```

How do I combine the two easily?

What's the context, you may ask? It's a console application where the Uri and the tilde relative path are manually constructed (that's actually a lie to get a "General solution", and not an Page.Resolve, etc. one).

I tried a few things (IE: HttpStyleUriParser) but I didn't get the right result. And I don't want to `String.Format("{0}://{1}{2}{3}")` my way there.

Comment: It's actually a .net application hosted WCF, but consider I didn't tell you that please.

Comment: I want a general solution, one that'll work everywhere as soon as you can get a Uri instance and the relative ~path you need to resolve. Something which use the .Net framework to its best extends instead of a simple String.Format(
                        "{0}://{1}{2}"
                        , uri.Scheme
                        , uri.Authority
                        , relativeUrl.TrimStart('~')
                    ); PS: Sorry I said it was a MVC before (my bad).

Answer (score 0):

The tilde character `~`is used in *nix systems for `home directory of currect user`.

In a .Net/C#/Windows application you must replace it by current user's home directory.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var uri = new Uri("http://www.contoso.com/");
        var relativeUrl = new Uri("~/Pages/SomePage.aspx".Replace("~",string.Empty),UriKind.Relative);
        Uri result;
        bool success = Uri.TryCreate(uri, relativeUrl,out result);

        Console.WriteLine(success);
        Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
    }

}
```

Output:

> True
>
> http://www.contoso.com/Pages/SomePage.aspx